# Is it possible to write Latex on Vega-Lite?

Tags: plot, latex, visualization, vega-lite

I'd like to use the "text" mark with a Latex expression and plot it using Vega-Lite. Is this possible? For example:

```
data = {x:[0,1,2,3],y:[0,1,2,3],t=["x^0","x^1","x^2","x^3"]}
{
  "data":data
  }],
  "mark": "text",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
    "text": {"field": "t", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Vega-Lite specifications do not support LaTeX math (the relevant feature request is [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2640)). But for simple mathematical expressions like the one in your example, you can often represent them using unicode text:

```json
{
  "data":{
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "t": "x⁰"},
      {"x": 1, "t": "x¹"},
      {"x": 2, "t": "x²"},
      {"x": 3, "t": "x³"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "text",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "text": {"field": "t", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]